# Compiling a program from 1988

Tags: c, linux, compilation, makefile, ubuntu-13.04

I am trying to compile a program from 1988. This program computes two-dimensional reconstructions from computerized-tomography-type experiments - only it takes into account first order diffraction of light.
I uploaded the archive there:

http://ubuntuone.com/1LXF5SBtUToJZ2lSgGJS47

It contains three folders:

```
Lib  - libraries
Man  - manuals on the programs
Src  - the actual source scripts
```

The `Src` and `Lib` both contains a `Makefile`. When I try to compile, I get:

```
/Src$ make
ncc david.c -g  -o david libuis.a -lm 
make: ncc: Command not found
make: *** [david] Error 127
```

**[EDIT]**
As suggested by  alexandernst I installed **nescc** and replaced ncc with nescc in the Makefile.

The file `libuis` is located in `Lib`. When I try to compile that:

```
/Lib$ make
make: `libuis' is up to date.
```

**[EDIT]**
As suggested by greghnz, I copied `Lib/libuis` to `Src/libuis.a`.

**[EDIT]**
As suggested by Evert, I symlinked `Lib/diffract.h` to `Src/diffract.h` and the compilation went further.

When I now try to compile, I get:

```
nescc david.c -g  -o david libuis.a -lm 
In file included from david.c:1:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
david.c: In function ‘main’:
david.c:93:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
david.c:177:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
david.c:200:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
david.c:400:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
david.c: In function ‘syntax’:
david.c:466:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
libuis.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [david] Error 1
```

I ran (I have no idea what that does)

```
ranlib libuis.a
```

and nothing was returned. When I rename the `Lib/libuis` and try to compile it, I get this:

```
nescc -c -g  FFTUnpack.c UnWrap.c UnWrap2d.c cfft.c cfft2d.c chamming.c cmodulate.c comm.c complex.c ctranspose.c debug.c ellipse.c fft.c fft2d.c findpoint.c findray.c findscat.c fmax.c fmin.c hamming.c mode.c modulate.c numout.c picout.c syntax.c transpose.c Green.c
In file included from UnWrap.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
UnWrap.c: In function ‘UnWrap’:
UnWrap.c:88:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
UnWrap.c:147:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
UnWrap.c: In function ‘PhaseRecurse’:
UnWrap.c:330:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
UnWrap.c:346:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
UnWrap.c: At top level:
UnWrap.c:454:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
UnWrap.c:488:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
In file included from UnWrap2d.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
UnWrap2d.c: In function ‘UnWrap2d’:
UnWrap2d.c:48:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
In file included from cfft.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from cfft2d.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from chamming.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from cmodulate.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from comm.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
comm.c: In function ‘comm’:
comm.c:28:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
In file included from complex.c:15:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from ctranspose.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from ellipse.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
ellipse.c: In function ‘readellipses’:
ellipse.c:33:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
ellipse.c:38:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
fft.c: In function ‘fft’:
fft.c:39:15: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘sin’ [enabled by default]
fft.c:39:22: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cos’ [enabled by default]
In file included from findpoint.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from findray.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
findray.c: In function ‘findray’:
findray.c:147:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
In file included from findscat.c:16:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
findscat.c: In function ‘findscat’:
findscat.c:187:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
findscat.c:187:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘abort’
findscat.c:197:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
findscat.c:197:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘abort’
findscat.c:207:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘abort’ [enabled by default]
findscat.c:207:4: error: too many arguments to function ‘abort’
findscat.c: At top level:
findscat.c:303:7: warning: extra tokens at end of #else directive [enabled by default]
findscat.c:314:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
In file included from hamming.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
In file included from mode.c:14:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
numout.c:31:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
picout.c: In function ‘picout’:
picout.c:29:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fwrite’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from picout.c:17:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:715:15: note: expected ‘size_t’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
picout.c:29:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘fwrite’
picout.c:30:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
syntax.c: In function ‘syntax’:
syntax.c:15:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
In file included from Green.c:5:0:
diffract.h:41:57: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘csqrt’ [enabled by default]
diffract.h:42:43: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘cexp’ [enabled by default]
Green.c: In function ‘Green’:
Green.c:37:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
Green.c:58:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive [enabled by default]
Green.c:59:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
Green.c:63:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
Green.c:89:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
make: *** [libuis] Error 1
```

I assume I have to compile **libuis** on my machine for this to work?
Cheers, Paul

Comment: And the diffract.h in /Src is empty..

Comment: `ncc` is what it's trying to compile with- find the line that contains `ncc` in Makefile and change it to something like `gcc` which you will probably have installed.

Comment: The Lib folder has `libuis` which is the compiled output of the Lib source code. Copy that file into the Src folder as `libuis.a`  ( so `cp ../Lib/libuis ./libuis.a`) Then run make again.  With your mod to the `Makefile` to use gcc you now get a whole bunch of c error messages.  Which is at least progress of a sort.

Comment: Don't replace ncc with gcc! You're looking for http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-1.x/doc/nesc/ncc.html

Comment: Or you might be looking for the Norcroft C Compiler from about that era. Might be hard to get though. http://www.codemist.co.uk/ncc/index.html

Comment: I really like the file `scat.c`.

Comment: @GregHNZ Thanks! I will write them. Maybe they can help.

Comment: I have a feeling that several of the errors you're now getting, are because those types, variables and constants are defined in `diffract.h`, but that's an empty file!. You'd better check that it's really empty, or that something went wrong when obtaining `diffract.h`.

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: copy or symlink `Lib/diffract.h` to `Src/diffract.h` and your compilation may get a lot further. That, or update the Makefile to set your include path to `Lib`.

Comment: @GregHNZ The very kind people from Codemist Ltd ruled out the Norcroft compiler: There is an `#ifdef BSD` statement and the Norcroft compiler was not used on BSD systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of most of the "conflicting types for built-in function" warnings add

```
#include <stdlib.h>`
```

to diffract.h and add `-std=c89` to CFLAGS in the Makefile. To get the stuff in Src to use the diffract.h in Lib you can use a symlink; another option is adding also `-I../Lib` to CFLAGS:

```
CFLAGS=-g -std=c89 -I../Lib
```

This will make it much easier to find the actual errors.

Some errors you'll have to fix by hand. For example `picout.c` tries to use `fwrite` as if it was `fprintf`, which makes me wonder if this code was ever working:

```
/* was: fwrite(stderr,"Error in writing picture.\n"); */
fprintf(stderr,"Error in writing picture.\n");
```

The `UnWrap.c` file uses a symbolic constant called `HUGE` which is not defined anywhere. In files under the RCS directory you can find this declaration, which you can add to diffract.h:

```
#define HUGE    1.701411733192644270e38
```

Also in a few places there are calls to `abort(1)`, which is an error because the abort function takes no parameters. In those cases just remove the `1`. Other than that the code seems to compile on GCC.

Comment: Thanks, everything compiled with gcc.